# Plupload Is Not Able to Access Error Message For JSON Object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, plupload

I have set up some PHP security checks on top of **Plupload** and generating error messages as it goes by using the same **JSON-RPC** notation as **Plupload** to be consistent. Though admittedly I am not quite familiar with this process.

An error message instance that I'm generating on the server side looks like this:

```
$err_msg = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 204, "message": "File type not supported. "}, "id" : "id"}';
```

On the receiving PHP script, the **Plupload** script is configured as follows:

```
            $('#uploader2').plupload('getUploader').bind('FileUploaded', function (uploader, file, info) {
        //alt 1 = THIS WORKS
        var err_msg = JSON.parse('{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 204, "message": "File type not supported. "}, "id" : "id"}');
        alert(info.error.code); // prints 204

        // alt 2 = GENERATES ERROR SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
        var err_msg = JSON.parse(info);

        // alt 3 = ASSUMING JQUERY IS ALREADY PARSING JSON
        alert(info); // gives object
        alert(info.error.code); // prints UNDEFINED 
        }
```

In `alt 1`, just to test, I pasted the string directly on the script; in that case it works fine and I can access the object as expected.

In `alt 2`, I am assuming that I need to parse the JSON and so this is what's giving me the syntax error. Looking elsewhere on SO, I found that that error indicates that jQuery is already parsing the JSON, so it should not be done again.

In `alt 3,` I try to access the object as one normally would but get `undefined`.

What am I missing here?

Adding console.log as suggested:

```
"{"jsonrpc" : "2.0", "error" : {"code": 204, "message": "Ne correspond pas aux types de fichiers acceptés. "}, "id" : "id"}"
```

Thanks

Comment: do a `console.log(info)` instead of an alert and you'll see exactly what the object is

Comment: Thanks @AlexTartan I have added that to the body of the question. It actually shows what was expected, but am still getting the UNDEFINED error when trying to access its components.

Answer (score 1):

In server side write the error message as plain text:

```
response.getWriter().write(message);  
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
```

In client side you will find the written message in:

```
Error: function(up, err) {
alert(err.response);    
...
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. Unfortunately I will not be able to confirm  and accept you answer as solution, after all this time. Great effort though.